# How to handle state of different type of input fields in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have some state variables which will change at some point in time. I want to know what is the proper way of handling such a huge amount of input variables. I had used the same code in Vue.js and the two-way data-binding works nicely for me. What will be the appropriate way to handle the below variables?

```
data() {
        return {
            valid: false,
            showDialog: true,
            showFullLoading: false,
            isImage: false,
            product: {
                name_en: "",
                name_ar: "",
                category: "",
                subcategory: "",
                description_en: "",
                description_ar: "",
                meta_title: "",
                meta_description: "",
                meta_keywords: "",
                price: 0.0,
                showSale: false,
                sale: 0.0,
                image: "",
                saleAfterStock: false,
                stock: 10
            },
            images: [
                { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
                { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
                { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
                { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() }
            ],
            attributes: [],
            defaultVariants: [],
            dataWeightClass: ["Gram", "Kilo Gram", "Pound"],
            dataDimensionClass: ["Centimeter", "Inch"],
            showAttributeDialog: false,
            sizeGuide: false,
            sizeGuides: [],
            attribute: {
                title_en: "",
                title_ar: "",
                description_en: "",
                description_ar: "",
                image: null,
                isImage: false
            },
            subcategories: [],
            options: [],
            variantsHeaders: [
                { text: "Variant", value: "name" },
                { text: "Price", value: "price" },
                { text: "Stock", value: "quantity" },
                { text: "Visibility", value: "visibility" }
            ],
            defaultVariantId: "",
            defaultPreviewId: ""
        };
    },
```

This is the data object in vue. I want to convert these data objects to state in react.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to write a `class` component or a function component?

Comment: A functional component.

Comment: Just a very minor note: They're *function* components. They're almost never [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). :-)

Comment: Hmmm. So anyway to convert this huge data sets to react states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're going to write a function component. In function components, the usual ways (in React itself) to store state are [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

- `useState` -

  > Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.
- `useReducer` -

  > Accepts a reducer of type `(state, action) => newState`, and returns the current state paired with a `dispatch` method. (If you’re familiar with Redux, you already know how this works.)

Outside React, there are tools like [Redux](https://redux.js.org) (with [React bindings](https://react-redux.js.org)), [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), and others that provide advanced state management.

Sticking with what's in React, if the various parts of your state object change in relation to one another, you probably want `useReducer`. If they're fairly distinct, you probably want `useState` (though some people never use `useReducer`, and others never use `useState`). From the `useReducer` documentation:

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one. `useReducer` also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass `dispatch` down instead of callbacks.

### `useState`

Using `useState`, you *can* have a megalithic state object like your data object, or you can break it up into individual parts. I would default to breaking it up into parts and only use a megalithic object if you have to, not least because updates are simpler. (Although that said, your data object is relatively flat, which means it's not *that* hard to update.)

Here's what that might look like:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
    const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(true);
    // ...
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({
        name_en: "",
        name_ar: "",
        category: "",
        subcategory: "",
        description_en: "",
        description_ar: "",
        meta_title: "",
        meta_description: "",
        meta_keywords: "",
        price: 0.0,
        showSale: false,
        sale: 0.0,
        image: "",
        saleAfterStock: false,
        stock: 10,
    });
    // ...
    const [images, setImages] = useState([
        { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
        { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
        { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
        { image: null, isImage: false, id: shortid.generate() },
    ]);

    // ...
}
```

You might define those initial values outside the component so you don't recreate objects and arrays unnecessarily, and for code clarity. For instance, if you had your existing data object as `defaults`, the above might be:

```
const defaults = { /*...*/ };
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(defaults.valid);
    const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(defaults.showDialog);
    // ...
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(defaults.product);
    // ...
    const [images, setImages] = useState(defaults.images);

    // ...
}
```

Either way, you then update those state members with calls to their setters. For `valid` and other simple primitives, it's very straight-forward, either:

```
setValid(newValue);
```

...or, if you're using the old value when setting the new one (like toggling), use the callback form so you're sure to get up-to-date state information:

```
setValid((oldValue) => !oldValue);
```

For objects and arrays, it's more complicated. You have to create a *new* object or array with the changes you want. For instance, to update `product`'s `category`:

```
setProduct((oldProduct) => { ...oldProduct, category: "new category" });
```

Notice how we make a *copy* of the old product object, then apply our update to it. The copy can be shallow (which is what spread syntax does).

To update `images` using an `id` variable that says which image to update, and (let's say) you want to set `isImage` to `true`:

```
setImages((oldImages) => oldImages.map((image) => {
    if (image.id === id) {
        return { ...image, isImage: true }; // Or whatever change it is
    }
    return image;
}));
```

Again, notice we didn't just assign a new image object to the existing array, we created a *new* array (in this case via `map`).

If you used a megalithic state object, like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(defaults);

    // ...
}
```

...then updating (say) `images` becomes a bit more difficult, although again your state object is fairly shallow so it's not that bad:

```
setState((oldState) => ({
    ...oldState,
    images: oldState.images.map((image) => {
        if (image.id === id) {
            return { ...image, isImage: true }; // Or whatever change it is
        }
        return image;
    })
}));
```

The key thing either way (individual or megalithic) is that **any** object or array that's a container for what you're changing (directly or indirectly) has to be copied. It's just that with a megalithic structure, you end up doing more copies since everything is inside a single container.

### `useReducer`

With `useReducer`, you again have the option of a single megalithic state object that the `dispatch` function updates (via your `reducer` function), or individual ones, each with their own `dispatch` and (probably) `reducer` functions. With `useReducer`, it's more common to have large state objects because one of the primary use cases is large structures where different parts may be updated by a single action. That might mean megalithic, or just larger chunks, etc.

The main difference is that your code in the component sends "actions" via `dispatch`, and then it's code in the `dispatch` function you write that does the updates to the state object and returns the new one.

Suppose you used `useReducer` with your megalithic object:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaults);

    // ...
}
```

Your `reducer` might look like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    const { type, ...actionParams } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case "update-image":
            const { id, ...updates } = actionParams;
            return {
                ...state,
                images: state.images.map((image) => {
                    if (image.id === id) {
                        return { ...image, ...updates };
                    }
                    return image;
                })
            };
        // ...other actions...
    }
}
```

and then in your component, instead of the `setImages` call shown in the `useState` section, you might do:

```
dispatch({ type: "update-image", id, isImage: true });
```

or similar (there are **lots** of different ways to write reducer functions).

The same rule applies to the state updates your `reducer` returns as to `useState` setters: **Any** object or array containing what you're updating has to be copied. So in this example copy the overall state object, the `images` array, and the image object we're updating. As with `useState`, if you used more individual `useReducer`s, you'd do a bit less copying.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using react's functional approach you can use useReducer hooker in order to locally (in the componente level) manage with state, or use redux to globally (app level) do the same.
You create an myreducer.js file and put something like this

```
export const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_PRICE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        product: {
          ...state.product,
          price: action.product.price
        }
      };
    }
};

export const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_PRICE": {
      state.product.price = action.product.price;
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

in your component you can use useReducer hook (if you just want to manage state locally)

```
import { useReducer } from 'react'
import { myReducer } from 'myReducer'

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [myState, dispatchMyState] = useReducer(myReducer, {})

  ...
  //where you need to update you can use this
  const handleAction = () => {
    dispatchMyState({
      type: "UPDATE_PRICE",
      dataToUpdate
    });
  }

  return <div onClick={handleAction}> anything</div>
}
```

Comment: But that would be a lot of boilerplate code. I need something simpler approach